# InstallReferrerClient.startConnection() throwing error

Tags: android

Some of my users ared getting the following error while using InstallReferrerClient.startConnection()

i'm following [android-developer's tutorial](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/google-play-referrer-api-track-and.html)

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.MyActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=com.google.android.finsky.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.externalreferrer.GetInstallReferrerService }

Does anybody know the cause?

Comment: This is unrelated to your issue(although I am facing this issue too !) but since you are using Install Referrer library, Can you have a look at this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003283/google-play-install-referrer-api-not-providing-utmcampaign-info

Comment: This is probably obsolete, since there is the install-referrer library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733287

Answer (score 4):

The permission `com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE` already existed in our code base but there was a property `tools:node="remove"` that was removing it from the merged manifest. After deleting `tools:node="remove"` the error didn't happen anymore and I was able to start a connection.

The documentation doesn't mention this permission, but I found a comment about it being a "requirement from Play Install Referrer API": https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78380811#comment22

Comment: But I saw my merged manifest file, it have that permission and that too without that tools:node="remove". But still i am getting the crash.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any other way to solve the issue besides what worked for me at the time. There is however an open issue reported here and people are waiting for a fix: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72926755

Answer (score -1):

I report this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70193614

OEM issue?

> This forum is for reporting android app development issues only.
>   However the issue you have logged is related to Samsung specific
>   devices which suggests that it could be related to OEM modifications
>   of the build.  Please reach out to OEM for such issue. We are closing
>   this issue here.

Comment: how do you know it is only occuring in Samsung?

Comment: The problem is that it's not just Samsung devices. Man from google says it's samsung OEM issue.

Comment: i see, so there's no solution by the moment

Comment: They closed that issue but another one was created stating this is NOT restricted to one OEM: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72926755

Answer (score -4):

You have to declare on manifest this permission below

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: will this stop the proble or only will prevent the app to stop?

Comment: this lead to success service binding

Comment: why isn't it on doc? where did you find it?

Comment: only support this feature on android studio so there isn't in on doc

Comment: @HoiIlJung any reference or source for your solution ?

Comment: It does work! You need the permission specially if you link the jar in eclipse.

Comment: When using Android Studio & gradle this permission is automatically added from the Manifest.xml in the AAR.