# Google Play Install Referrer API not providing utmCampaign info

Tags: android, google-play, google-ads-api

I am using [Google Play Install Referrer API 1.0](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library.html) to collect the install referrer information. The API is providing the **utmSource** and **utmMedium** data perfectly, but **utmCampaign** is completely missing.

I have enabled autoTagging in `Google` `Adwords` and the `FireBase` Analytics is showing the **utmCampaign** data accurately.

Examples of value returned by :

```
ReferrerDetails response = mReferrerClient.getInstallReferrer();
response.getInstallReferrer();
```

is as follows :

**utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic**

**utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set)**

I am wondering why utmCampaign data is missing.

Anyone faced similar issue and has any solution? It is critical to find out the Campaign source information for us.

Comment: How did you test this?

Comment: collected logs from live app

Comment: Hello, did you solve this problem?

Comment: I am facing same issue. Did you got any solution?

Comment: did you got the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Google play store checks all the mail accounts which are logged into Google play and if you are logged in with work email (enterprise domain email id)it sets the UTM  property as `utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set)`.

So try removing work email from google play store and verify.

Use [Google Play URL Builder](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder) to generate campaign URL.

Comment: I did not get "try removing work email from google play store and verify". Please elaborate. I am getting "utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic" through utm_source is set different name but still getting as google-play. Please suggest what to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(getActivity().getIntent())
        .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                    //utm_campaign=cam&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=xyz
                    Uri deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                    if (deepLink.toString().contains("utm_campaign") ||
                            deepLink.toString().contains("utm_medium") ||
                            deepLink.toString().contains("utm_source")) {
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(getActivity(), new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is a complete another way of getting campaign information. My question is why the Play Install Referrer library is missing that information? and that too missing it partially. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @binaryKarmic Pls check that referral URL must be having utm_campaign information.

Comment: That is what i have mentioned in the questions."I have enabled autoTagging in Google Adwords. FireBase Analytics is showing the utmCampaign data accurately."