# Why Google play services dependency automatically added com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE permission

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, install-referrer

Recently i have updated google play services dependency version to 15.0.0 it automatically added the below permission.

i don't no wheather i need this [Google Play Referrer API](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/google-play-referrer-api-track-and.html) permission or not

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />
```

I'm able to remove this permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" 
tools:node="remove" />
```

but i need know which dependency will need BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE permission does the dependency really need this permission or not.

App Level Gradle

```
dependencies {

     ext {
        support_library_version = '27.0.2'
        google_play_services_version = '15.0.0'
    }

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${support_library_version}"

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${google_play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${google_play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${google_play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${google_play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:${google_play_services_version}"

}
```

Project Level Gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
  }
```

**Note:** For referrer tracking am already using google analytics

```
<service   android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you include it? According to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706419/installreferrerclient-startconnection-throwing-error) it may throw InstallReferrerClient.startConnection() errors if it's not included.

Comment: am not doing anything related to this permission BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE it added automatically

Comment: @SarathKumar have you find any solution.? Is there any side effects on the app after forcefully removing permission form manifeast file.?

Comment: @patelvatsal It forcefully added the permission tools:node="remove" is not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Won't Fix (Intended behavior)

For More details check  [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78380811#comment22)

Comment: What library is this in regards to?  There is no 15.0.2 for OP's dependencies.

Comment: If you don't need that permission in your app, just add this to the bottom of AndroidManifest.xml: <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" tools:node="remove"/> (per the Google issue in this answer)

Comment: Specifying the details in the answer's body, without the need to open the link, would be very helpful. It's not about laziness, it's about link rot (that can happen at any moment)…