# How to test install referrer with Google's installreferrer library?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, install-referrer

There are lots of examples how to test "default" way of detecting install referrer, but there is not example how to test `com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer` library.

Examples like

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER 
                       -n your.package.name/path.to.receiver --es referrer
                       --es referrer "EXTRA_STRING_VALUE"
```

do not work because we don't know `receiver` path. So how to test it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the [InstallReferrerClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/installreferrer/api/InstallReferrerClient.html), there doesn't seem to be any `BroadcastReceiver` registered in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. The library just binds to the system's install referrer service ...

```
private static final String SERVICE_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.android.vending";
private static final String SERVICE_NAME = "com.google.android.finsky.externalreferrer.GetInstallReferrerService";
private static final String SERVICE_ACTION_NAME = "com.google.android.finsky.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE";
```

The client receives referrer `utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic` upon manual install. There is no `BroadcastReceiver` exposed (but the `InstallReferrerService` should have one).

The keys of the raw `Intent` `Bundle` are: `install_referrer`, `referrer_click_timestamp_seconds` and `install_begin_timestamp_seconds` if you want to try emulating it - but the `onInstallReferrerSetupFinished()` callback will deliver the result indirectly.

The documentation also states:

> The install referrer information will be available for 90 days and won't change unless the application is reinstalled. *To avoid unnecessary API calls in your app, you should invoke the API only once during the first execution after install.* Your app can listen to the system broadcast `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH` to identify the app's first execution.

---

So this should be an `intent-filter` for `action` `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH`, which subsequently connects the `InstallReferrerClient` to the `InstallReferrerService`. One cannot trigger `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH` with `adb`, because it filters for a "protected broadcast action string", therefore it might only be triggered when installing from Play Store.

The implementation, according to the documentation, might look alike:

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receiver.PackageStatusReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

`PackageStatusReceiver.java`:

```
public class PackageStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements InstallReferrerStateListener {

    protected static final String LOG_TAG = PackageStatusReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    private InstallReferrerClient referrerClient;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction() != null) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH)) {
                this.referrerClient = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(context).build();
                this.referrerClient.startConnection(this);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(int responseCode) {
        switch (responseCode) {
            case InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.OK:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "InstallReferrer Response.OK");
                try {
                    ReferrerDetails response = referrerClient.getInstallReferrer();
                    String referrer = response.getInstallReferrer();
                    long clickTimestamp = response.getReferrerClickTimestampSeconds();
                    long installTimestamp = response.getInstallBeginTimestampSeconds();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "InstallReferrer " + referrer);
                    referrerClient.endConnection();
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "" + e.getMessage());
                }
                break;
            case InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "InstallReferrer Response.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED");
                break;
            case InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "InstallReferrer Response.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE");
                break;
            case InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.SERVICE_DISCONNECTED:
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "InstallReferrer Response.SERVICE_DISCONNECTED");
                break;
            case InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.DEVELOPER_ERROR:
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "InstallReferrer Response.DEVELOPER_ERROR");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected() {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "InstallReferrer onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected()");
    }
}
```

To test this, you'd need referrer links to the Play Store and then install the package through them... else only the default referrer will be logged (besides the intent cannot even be triggered, when properly implementing the client).

Comment: On which parameter i get UTM parameters?

Comment: I will suggest to move referrerClient.endConnection() call to "finnaly" block in InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.OK case because response.getInstallReferrer() can throw exception and the connection will remain opened

Comment: What does it mean `referrer information will be available for 90 days and won't change unless the application is reinstalled`? Should I store the data in the local storage forever or will I need to perform specific action after 90 days?? Please help me

Answer (score 2):

You can test install referrer by setting up internal test version of your app in Play Market console. After that, use modified link from Play Market URL Builder.

Answer (score 1):

I've used physical device via USB.

**1** put the app  on Play Store approved

**2** Most important step:  build right link on [e.g. I used only last value](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#campaign-params) . Also important under *Ad Network* field pickup *Custom*,
otherwize it will work on tests but wont  when production w/o  specified ad network

**3** Send the link to email on the phone

**4** Click on the link just emailed. It runs  *Play Store* (Don't Install from play Store)

**5** Add [what's needed](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library) to the main activity (dont use depricated and outdated docs). Launch  with *Android Studio* the app just from *Run* button. Press *Home* to turn app out  the screen and press *Recent* button  remove the app swiping

**6** Play store "Install" button (now) should  look as "Open"
Tap the button. Now  you can handle *response.getInstallReferrer()* e.g. to see that in logs